# Unable to update label text in ASCX from event handler

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've two custom ASP.NET Web Form Controls below:

1. Main.ASCX
2. Account_Selection.ASCX

Main contains Account_Selection. The Main ACX contains the event handler for drop down that lives on Account_Selection ASCX.

I would like to show the error message on Main ASCX if there are issues on contract selection. However the message never gets displayed. Spent couple of hours already but
it never works. The event handler definately gets called. I'm wondering if it's an update panel or event hanlder. Could someone please help, below is the code snippets:

**Account_Selection.ACX** has below:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upContracts" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>

            <asp:DropDownList ID="dropDown" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnDropOptionSelected">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Select Account" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>               
            </asp:DropDownList>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**On Code behind**:

```
public event RequestContractTypeEventHandler RequestContract;
 public void OnDropOptionSelected(string currentContractDescription, string currentContractNumber)
        {
            if (RequestContract != null)
            {
                RequestContract(this, new ContractForAccountEventArgs { ContractDescription = currentContractDescription, Contract = currentContractNumber });
            }
        }
```

**Main ASCX has below:**

```
<div>
    <OnlineUserControl:ContractsForAccountControl ID="ucContractsForAccountControl" runat="server" />
</div>

<div style="display:none" id="divError" runat="server" class="error-container">
    <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" CssClass="labelError"  runat="server"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
   private void InitializeControls()
        {
            ucContractsForAccountControl.RequestContract += new global::OnlineSelfService.Web.usercontrol.RequestContractTypeEventHandler(contractsForAccountControl_RequestContract);
        }

void contractsForAccountControl_RequestContract(object sender, global::OnlineSelfService.Web.usercontrol.ContractForAccountEventArgs e)
        {

            this.lblMsg.Text="something bad happened!;  //THIS LINE DOESN'T GET DISPLAYED
            this.divError.Style.Add("display", "");  //IN DEBUGGER THIS LINE SHOWS "Cannot get inner content of divError because the contents are not literal"

                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the update panel that is causing the issue. The way an update panel works is that **only** the content within the update panel is updated. You cannot update any controls outside of the update panel that initiated the "partial post back". The reason it is called a "partial post back" is because Render is only called for the child controls within the update panel. A more accurate description for what happens is a "full post" (all input control values on the page are sent in the request aka post) with a "partial back" (response) that only contains the markup for the items within the update panel. The fact that all input control values (including the hidden viewstate input control) are sent in the request makes an update panel more expensive than a json ajax call that only posts only the values that are needed for the response (in this case the selected account) but is less expensive than a full post back because only the markup for the controls in the update panel (plus viewstate) are returned in the response.

**Possible solutions**: Option 2 is my recommendation, but I am not sure how many other pages already use this control, and you would need to update each of these pages to add the UpdatePanel.

**Option 1**: move the error label within the UpdatePanel in Account_Selection.ASCX.  This option will not help you if you want to update other data outside of the UpdatePanel when the selected account is changed.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upContracts" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>

            <asp:DropDownList ID="dropDown" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnDropOptionSelected">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Select Account" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>               
            </asp:DropDownList>
<div style="display:none" id="divError" runat="server" class="error-container">
    <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" CssClass="labelError"  runat="server"></asp:Label>
</div>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code behind:

```
public event RequestContractTypeEventHandler RequestContract;
 public void OnDropOptionSelected(string currentContractDescription, string currentContractNumber)
        {
            if (RequestContract != null)
            {
            try{
                RequestContract(this, new ContractForAccountEventArgs { ContractDescription = currentContractDescription, Contract = currentContractNumber });
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                this.lblMsg.Text="something bad happened!";  
                this.divError.Style.Add("display", "");  
            }
            }
        }
```

**Option 2**: remove the UpdatePanel from the "Account_Selection" user control, and move it to your ASPX page and wrap the UpdatePanel in the ASPX around the content you want to update.

Your ASPX page then would look something like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upContracts" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <OnlineUserControl:MainControlTagName ID="myMainControl" runat="server" />
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Thanks any idea how this can be fixed for code provided?

Comment: Move the error label within the update panel in the account selection user control.

Comment: you saved my day putting the usercontrol inside the same Update Panel